# Referencing custom library in SAPUI5 causes 404 when loading the library

Tags: javascript, sapui5

We wrote a custom library that we now want to reference in our main application.
Thus we added the following two entries to the consumer's neo-app.json:

```
   {
        "path": "/webapp/resources/some/lib",
        "target": {
            "type": "application",
            "name": "somedemolib"
        },
        "description": "..."
    }, {
        "path": "/resources/some/lib",
        "target": {
            "type": "application",
            "name": "somedemolib"
        },
        "description": "..."
    }
```

and the following to the manifest.json of the libs consumer:

```
"dependencies": {
   "minUI5Version": "1.30.0",
   "libs": {
        ...
        "some.lib": {
           "minVersion": "1.0.0"
       }
   }
},
```

However upon loading the web-app I can see a HTTP404 when trying to load the library under the following path:

```
Uncaught Error: failed to load 'some/lib/library.js' from ../../resources/some/lib/library.js: 404 - Not Found
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare your custom scripts in the first lines of your components.js

First of all you have to declare the path of your custom lib folder: 
https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/docs/api/symbols/jQuery.sap.html#.registerModulePath

```
jQuery.sap.registerResourcePath("libs/custom", "/scripts/customlibs");
```

After that call you are able to load your script from that path with this call:

```
jQuery.sap.require("libs.custom.nameofyourscript");
```

"libs.custom" points to that folder you have registered previously and then your are able to import the script by its name. So your components.js looks like this:

```
jQuery.sap.registerResourcePath("libs/custom", "/scripts/customlibs");
jQuery.sap.require("libs.custom.nameofyourscript");

// Now the declaration of the components starts
sap.ui.core.UIComponent.extend("yourappname.Component", {
// ...
```

Comment: Consider using the `sap.ui.define` syntax instead of `jQuery.sap.require`.

Comment: Shouldn't this already handled by the entries in the manifest and neo-app.json?
Because the code above is actually generated when I use the "Add reference to library" feature of the WebIDE itself.

Comment: This is the way I get my custom scripts to work. And regarding to your error message it looks like that the framework is searching for the script at the wrong folder. Try it out and set the reference path manually and not by the IDE.